# 302 redirect language subfolder to website root in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

We have temporarily suspended the French and German versions of a client site built in Wordpress, as the translations were extremely outdated. We want to 302 the www.example.com/fra/ and www.example.com/deu/ subfolders and all related URLs to www.example.com until the new translations are ready.

Researching on stackoverflow lead me to add the following code to .htaccess, but it doesn't work completely. www.example.com/fra/ redirects correctly, but www.example.com/fra/xxx redirects to www.example.com/xxx, while example.com/fra (no trailing slash) gives a 404.

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/fra/.*$ http://www.example.com
RedirectMatch 302 ^/deu/.*$ http://www.example.com
```

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Of course, it needed the wildcard. Thanks very much, that does exactly what we wanted, much appreciated

Comment: Strangely, the code above no longer works. Entering a URL like www.example.com/fra/example doesn't redirect to example.com - what happens is the language subfolder is removed from the URL, leaving example.com/example, which in most cases gives a 404. Can anybody suggest any solution? Thank you.